# ValueError in python while reading .txt file for Wordcloud project

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
      with open('checking.txt', 'r') as file:
      data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
        print(data)

       word_cloud = WordCloud(collocations = False, background_color = 'black').generate(data)`
```

This is the error that I got:

ValueError: We need at least 1 word to plot a word cloud, got 0.

**Edit**:
The problem was that I had not provided the absolute path for reading the text file.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: hey rubenskx. Welcome to SO. Please don't post text as an image. You can just copy&paste it. Images are not indexable by search engines and also not accessible by many people with disabilities, just to name two of the many reasons to not paste test as images. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this worked ?

```
with open('abcd.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '')
    print(data)

word_cloud = WordCloud(collocations = False, background_color = 'black').generate(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please provide the contents of `checking.txt` or at least what does `print(data)` prints. I tried on my dummy data and it works. If I `print(data)` it should print the words separated by space and the datatype of the data variable is `<class 'str'>`. Check if it is in that format or not.

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Please check if you are reading the file in a proper way. Your indentation is wrong first of all.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the content of the txt file or some dummy data which is exactly like the content of that txt file.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the text ,I don't know how to upload text file to the original question.

Comment: Ok I have solved the issue it was because I had not included absolute/complete path of the file thanks anyway